# How to prevent websocket from closing after certain time in angular5?

Tags: websocket, rxjs, angular5

I am using 'rxjs-websockets' to connect with websockets. But after certain time (approx 2min)
the connection gets closed. How can I hold the connection until it is manually closed.

Here is the code snippet I use

```
constructor(private socketService: WebSocketService) {}

this.socketService.connect('/endpoint');
this.socketSubscription = this.socketService.messages
      .subscribe(result => {            
            // perform operation
    });
```

This is the WebSocketService

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {QueueingSubject} from 'queueing-subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import websocketConnect from 'rxjs-websockets';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retryWhen';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

@Injectable()
export class WebSocketService {
  private inputStream: QueueingSubject<string>;
  public messages: Observable<string>;

  constructor() {    
  }

  public connect(socketUrl) {
      this.messages = websocketConnect(
        socketUrl,
        this.inputStream = new QueueingSubject<string>()
      ).messages.retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(1000))
        .map(message => JSON.parse(message))
        .share();
  }

  public send(message: string): void {
    this.inputStream.next(message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Websockets usually holds the connection for a long time interval with the help of some message exchange.
In our case we can call it as 'ping => pong', client sends message 'ping' and server may respond with message 'pong'.

You can send ping every 30 seconds as follows.

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.socketService.send('ping');
}, 30000);
```

As you are converting every message received at WebSocketService into JSON, you have to make these change
to avaoid JSON Parsing error.

```
export class WebSocketService {
.
.
.

    public connect(socketUrl) {
      this.messages = websocketConnect(
        socketUrl,
        this.inputStream = new QueueingSubject<string>()
      ).messages.retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(1000))
        //parse messages except pong to avoid JSON parsing error
        .map(message => message === 'pong' ? message : JSON.parse(message))
        .share();
    }
.
.
.
}
```